# How to host webserver with domain name?

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, apache-virtualhost, domain

I bought a domain with Namecheap and want to host the server by myself but with the domain name. How do I do this? Whenever I search on Google I only get useless results telling me things I don't understand; assuming I know where to find this conf file, or that I can just use their hosting service. I want to know how to host it myself but with the domain name that I purchased. And please, speak English instead of HexabinaryDNS. I barely know what a DNS is and where to find it so please speak easy for me, I am new to this. I have the following addons: WhoisGuard, Namecheap VPN and Namecheap PremiumDNS.

My distro is Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 1):

1 you have a domain name

2 you need to host the domain name on name servers; you need to give your domain name vendor 2 IPs

3 you need to tell your name servers what IP you will be using for your domain (maybe the IP for your home)

4 you need to setup your rpi and local network to listen for requests to your domain.

All of the above can be bundled as a service in different combinations depending on what you want to do yourself. PremiumDNS sounds like you won't have to run your own name servers, so just

1 use the webui to point your doman at your home ip

2 forward port 80 to your pi

3 install your web server software of choice

but really you should educate yourself or pay someone to do it properly for you.

Comment: Where (for Apache2) do I find the files where I can change the DNSes?

Comment: @ExtraMerc you don't because Apache2 is a web server not a name server. bind9 is a name server, or use Namecheap service.

Comment: What I mean is how to set it up in my configuration. I know that I can't change my domain or DNS servers, but to word it correctly, where exactly in my config files do I find the settings where I set the DNS servers?

Comment: @ExtraMerc "you need to give your domain name vendor 2 IPs" ... you can change your name servers, but if you don't have any and your domain vendor provided you with 2, then step 2 is taken care of already.

Comment: Oh. I see. So you mean you're not talking about the DNS servers? Which 2 IPs do I give Namecheap then? I already figured out how to give the first one, which is my public IP. Where would I find this second one you mention?

Comment: @ExtraMerc, if you gave N.C. your public IP then the second list applies to you. (N.C. alrady did all required DNS things for you.)